# Lightning Component tab not loading in Trial org

Tags: lightning-aura-components, managed-package, lightning

I have a lightning application in a managed package which I am testing across multiple orgs, and I ran into an issue today where the page would not load on a Trial (Enterprise edition).

```
Uncaught rerender threw an error in 'markup://one:auraContainer' [rerender threw an error in 'markup://aura:expression' [$ is not defined]]
throws at https://myorg-dev5.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/x4ZmsozINtoTVrt_2eFxRg/aura_prod.js:2:15
Error,    at Error (native),    at new <anonymous> (https://myorg-dev5.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/x4ZmsozINtoTVrt_2eFxRg/aura_prod.js:180:302),    at https://myorg-dev5.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/x4ZmsozINtoTVrt_2eFxRg/aura_prod.js:1:1
```

It seems like it is trying to use jQuery without loading jQuery. I took a look at the console and I see another error

```
Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading 'https://myorg-dev5.my.salesforce.com/0A3?setupid=ImportedPackage&retURL=%...
dcIFrameOrigin=https://myorg-dev5.lightning.force.com&sfdcIFrameHost=web': 'ALLOW-FROM https://myorg-dev5.lightning.force.com' is not a recognized directive. The header will be ignored.
```

Attempting to access the page breaks LEX in general, as can be seen [here](https://i.imgur.com/5q4lKi4.gifv), leading to more errors and eventually [crashing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfxvE.png) and displaying an error message in the console

```
gA {name: "AuraError", message: "Invalid component tried calling function [set] with arguments [v._menuItems,[object Object]]", tf: Array[6], severity: "QUIET", o: "InvalidComponent"…}
```

I do not see the same issue occur on any other versions, and this is my test result from testing across different types of orgs.

Free - Developer Edition   WORKS
Active - Enterprise Edition   WORKS
Demo - Enterprise Edition WORKS
Trial - Enterprise Edition DOES NOT WORK